# Passing a link or a button as components to SimpleForm wrappers

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

i want an input to be renderized like this template:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text"> 
    <span class="input-group-btn"> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="inline-button">Do Action!</button> 
      <!-- this could be a link or a button -->
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And i want a way to create the form via SimpleForm passing the generated button to simple form wrapper in order to use it as a component in a wrapper:

```
<%= simple_form_for(something) do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :some_attribute, wrapper: "inline_button", button: "inline-button" %>
  <%= button_tag "inline-button" %>
<% end %>
```

(I know this code won't work, it's just an example)

The wrapper would be:

```
config.wrappers "inline_button", tag: 'div', class: 'form-group' do |ib|
  ...
  ib.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'input-group col-lg-10' do |ig| 
    ig.use :input, class: 'form-control'
    ig.wrapper tag: 'span', class: 'input-group-btn' do |btn|
      btn.use :button, class: 'btn btn-primary
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The input works like this:

```
<%= form.input :some_button, wrapper: "inline", inline_button:  link_to("Something", "#") %>
```

The wrapper:

```
config.wrappers "inline_button", tag: 'div', class: 'form-group' do |ib|
...
  ib.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'input-group col-lg-10' do |ig| 
    ig.use :input, class: 'form-control'
    ig.wrapper tag: 'span', class: 'input-group-btn' do |btn|
      btn.use :button, class: 'btn btn-primary
    end
  end
end
```

Then, in config/initializers/simple_form/inline_button_component.rb

```
module SimpleForm
  module Components
    # Needs to be enabled in order to do automatic lookups
    module InlineElements
      # Name of the component method
      def inline_element(wrapper_options = nil)
        @inline_element ||= begin
          options[:inline_element].to_s.html_safe if options[:inline_element].present?
        end
      end

      # Used when the number is optional
      def has_inline_element?
        inline_element.present?
      end
    end
  end
end

SimpleForm::Inputs::Base.send(:include, SimpleForm::Components::InlineElements)
```